# Java Replace sub-string (pattern) by another sub-string (value) issue

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, replaceall

I have a small api to convert a string to another string by updating property holders (pattern {{property_name}}

**Here is my try:**

```
public class TestApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put("title", "login");

        String sourceTitle = "<title>{{ title }}</title>";
        System.out.println(updatePropertyValue(sourceTitle, props));

        // Print: <title>login</title>

        // ERROR if
        props.put("title", "${{__messages.loginTitle}}");
        System.out.println(updatePropertyValue(sourceTitle, props));
        // Expected: <title>${{__messages.loginTitle}}</title>

        // Exception:

        // Exception in thread "main" 
        // java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: named capturing group has 0 length name
        // at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:838)
    }

    static String updatePropertyValue(String line, Map<String, String> properties) {
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
            String holder = "\\{\\{\\s*" + entry.getKey() + "\\s*\\}\\}";
            line = Pattern.compile(holder, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
                          .matcher(line).replaceAll(entry.getValue());
        }
        return line;
    }
}
```

It works fine If the property value does not have any special characters such as $.

Please assume that property keys include letters only.

Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation of the `replaceAll` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String))? Especially what it says about dollar signs?

Comment: @RealSkeptic: Yes, I took a look at it. What I need is there is another solution for it. Thanks!

Comment: Use `.replaceAll(entry.getValue().replace("$", "\\$"))` in the `updatePropertyValue` method.

Comment: Well, as it says in the same documentation, add a backslash before the `$`, and the problem will be solved.

Comment: Thank you!. I thought I need to have a list of special chars. Not only $. But it seems $ is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Pattern.quoteReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)) to escape all metacharacters in the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to regex escape `entry.getKey()` part. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60161/1398531) should help in doing that.

Comment: There is no issue with entry.getKey(). There is issue with entry.getValue() - property value.

Comment: Note that the replacement should also be escaped, not just the pattern.