# Escaping regex variable

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex `Pattern.compile("^" + prefix + "[a-zA-Z]")`, where it'll match the prefix in the beginning of a word, it works fine for `!` for example, but when I try using `?` it breaks, as an attempt to escape it I tried turning it into `Pattern.compile("^\\" + prefix + "[a-zA-Z]")` but I get the error `Illegal/unsupported escape sequence`, doing `\\\\` seemed to make it handle the `?` correctly but then the `!` stopped working.
I'm kinda lost on how I would prevent the String from affecting the pattern itself.

Comment: Use `"\\?"` to escape it. There are 2 backslashes because it's also in a Java string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape text for regular expression in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160/how-to-escape-text-for-regular-expression-in-java). E.g. `Pattern.compile("^" + Pattern.quote(prefix) + "[a-zA-Z]")`

Comment: How about `Pattern.compile(prefix.startsWith("?") ? "^\\\\" : "^" + prefix + "[a-zA-Z]")`