# How can I remove whitespaces around the first occurrence of specific char?

Tags: java, string, char, whitespace

How can I remove the whitespaces before and after a specific char? I want also to remove the whitespaces only around the first occurrence of the specific char. In the examples below, I want to remove the whitespaces before and after the first occurrence of `=`.

For example for those strings:

```
something =           is equal to   =   something
something      =      is equal to   =   something
something      =is equal to   =   something
```

I need to have this result:

```
something=is equal to   =   something
```

Is there any regular expression that I can use or should I check for the index of the first occurrence of the char `=`?

Answer (score 1):

```
private String removeLeadingAndTrailingWhitespaceOfFirstEqualsSign(String s1) {
    return s1.replaceFirst("\\s*=\\s*", "=");
}
```

Notice this matches all whitespace including tabs and new lines, not just space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression `\w*\s*=\s*` to get all matches. From there call trim on the first index in the array of matches.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FWoRNs/1).

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can create a Regex that matches optional whitespace followed by your pattern followed by optional whitepace, and then replace the first instance.

```java
public static String replaceFirst(final String toMatch, final String forIP) {
    // string you want to match before and after
    final String quoted = Pattern.quote(toMatch);
    final Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("\\s*" + quoted + "\\s*");
    final Matcher match = patt.matcher(forIP);
    return match.replaceFirst(toMatch);
}
```

For your inputs this gives the expected result - assuming toMatch is `=`.  It also works with arbitrary bigger things - eg.. imagine giving "is equal to" instead ... getting

```
something =is equal to=   something
```

For the simple case you can ignore the quoting, for an arbitrary case it helps (although as
[many contributors have pointed out before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160/how-to-escape-text-for-regular-expression-in-java) the Pattern.quoting isn't good for every case).

The simple case thus becomes

```java
return forIP.replaceFirst("\\s*" + forIP + "\\s*", forIP);
```

OR

```java
return forIP.replaceFirst("\\s*=\\s*", "=");
```