# Matching whole words with special characters with a dynamically built pattern

Tags: java, regex

I need to match an exact substring in a string in Java. I've tried with

```
String pattern = "\\b"+subItem+"\\b";
```

But it doesn't work if my substring contains non alphanumerical characters.
I want this to work exactly as the "Match whole word only" function in Notepad++.
Could you help?

Comment: What can `subItem` look like when "it does not work"? What do you consider a word?

Comment: Any combination of alphanumerical and non alphanumerical characters. Like: Data[3] or pst->numberOfTx.

Comment: So, any non-whitespace? Does `String pattern = "(?<!\\S)"+Pattern.quote(subItem)+"(?!\\S)";` solve the issue?

Comment: On this string:
Data[3]=(uint8)Data[1];
It doesn't work for searching Data[3]

Comment: Ok, if the words with special chars at the start/end are not to be glued to word chars, try `String pattern = "(?<!\\w)"+Pattern.quote(subItem)+"(?!\\w)";` Else, you will need to build word boundaries by checking the first/final chars in the `subItem`

Comment: My guess is your `subItem` content isn't escaped. So when it is `Data[3]`, it looks for `Data3` instead of `Data[3]`, because `[` and `]` are special characters in Regex.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape text for regular expression in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160/how-to-escape-text-for-regular-expression-in-java)

Comment: It might be more complex than just replacing `subItem` with `Pattern.quote(subItem)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what's the difference between you last comment and the first one? Because the first one seems to work fine. I mean `String pattern = "(?<!\\w)"+Pattern.quote(subItem)+"(?!\\w)";`

Comment: @RobertIlin The `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)` might fail to find `[Data]` in `text[Data]text`. I understood you need to match these cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest either *unambigous word boundaries* (that match a string only if the search pattern is not enclosed with letters, digits or underscores):

```java
String pattern = "(?<!\\w)"+Pattern.quote(subItem)+"(?!\\w)";
```

where `(?<!\w)` matches a location not preceded with a word char and `(?!\w)` fails if there is no word char immediately after the current position (see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hJSlMZ/3)), or, you can use a variation that takes into account leading/trailing special chars of the potential match:

```java
String pattern = "(?:\\B(?!\\w)|\\b(?=\\w))" + Pattern.quote(subword) + "(?:(?<=\\w)\\b|(?<!\\w)\\B)";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hJSlMZ/2).

*Details*:

- `(?:\B(?!\w)|\b(?=\w))` - either a non-word boundary if the next char is not a word char, or a word boundary if the next char is a word char
- `Data\[3\]` - this is a quoted `subItem`
- `(?:(?<=\w)\b|(?<!\w)\B)` - either a word boundary if the preceding char is a word char, or a non-word boundary if the preceding char is not a word char.